# How to return just the values from sqlplus using set variables?

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

Can someone please help me here?
Looks like I setup the right values in the set variables, but it's returning lot of things. See below:

```
################################
# Main
################################

RETVAL=`sqlplus user/pass@DB <<EOF
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
SELECT process_id, source, destination, type FROM table WHERE process_id IN ('12311','12322');
EXIT;
EOF`
if [ -z "$RETVAL" ]; then
  echo "No rows returned from database"
  exit 0
else
  echo $RETVAL
fi
```

The output is:

SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production on Thu Jun 27 19:37:39 2013 Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved. Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options SQL> SQL> 12311 ,AAA BBB ,2 12322 ,AAA BBB ,5 SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

I just would like:

12311, AAA, BBB, 2,
12322, AAA, BBB, 5,

*the commas is also not right

Comment: Can the values of user/pass@DB be substituted with variables? Is it possible to have $user/$pass@$dbname instead?

Comment: Also inside the sql can you have more variables? like  FROM table WHERE process_id IN --> from table@$dblinkname is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -s option of sqlplus to supress:

```
sqlplus -s user/pass@DB
```